# Two same components in one parent, first one override the second

Tags: angular

I have a component which contains two subcomponents, the subcomponent are identical:

```
<!-- Some code ... -->

<app-upload-button
  #idBook
  [accept]="'image/*'"
  (loadend)="onImageLoaded('#this-idbook-preview')"
>
</app-upload-button>

<!-- Some code ... -->

<app-upload-button
  #userIdBook
  [accept]="'image/*'"
  (loadend)="onImageLoaded('#this-user-idbook-preview')"
>
</app-upload-button>

<!-- Some code ... -->
```

As we can see the two elements have different references `#idBook` and `#userIdBook`, and also the string passed in the function `onImageLoaded` are different `'#this-idbook-preview'` and `'#this-user-idbook-preview'`.

My problem is that no matter if I interact with `#idBook` or `#userIdBook`, it seems like `#idBook` is always replacing the other element. When I test the string in `onImageLoaded`, I always get `'#this-idbook-preview'`, even if I clicked on the second element. Also, only the variables of the first element get modified, the second one is always unchanged.

What's the problem here? And how to fix it?

Edit: UploadButtonComponent code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-upload-button',
  templateUrl: './upload-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-button.component.css']
})
export class UploadButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() accept: string;
  @Output() loadend: EventEmitter<void>;

  file: File;
  fileData: string;

  constructor() {
    this.loadend = new EventEmitter();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.accept === undefined) {
      this.accept = '*';
    }
  }

  readFile(): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = (event: any) => {
      this.fileData = event.target.result;
      this.loadend.emit();
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
  }

  onChange(event: any): void {
    this.file = event.target.files[0];
    this.readFile();
  }
}
```

Edit 2: Mini project

I created a mini project to show the problem, the link is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yafbuiKYUQ-POeNAXHu0ATyo8l84ydCE

Comment: Can you show the component code ?

Comment: @Random Yes, I just added it

Comment: there is no reason to this behavior. Can you reproduce it in a plunker ? Looks more like a refresh problem (what you see in the browser is not the code you see)

Comment: @Random I create a mini project that shows the problem, here's the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yafbuiKYUQ-POeNAXHu0ATyo8l84ydCE

Comment: Ok, the problem is from inside your upload button... making an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Angular, you have to be careful with native HTML rules. One of those is you must not have multiple elements with the same id. Here, you use a constant id inside your component, so when you use this id, they will all trigger the first component (which contain the first element of the page with this id).
So you have 2 solutions.

1. The component calling the upload-button gives him a unique id. This may be dangerous if you forget every id has to be unique.
2. Do something to be sure the same id will never be used twice, using a counter

You can do it this way:

```
// component
export class UploadButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  static nextIdNumber: number = 0; // will increment for each generated component
  public myId: string; // generated unique HTML id
  // ...

  constructor() {
    // ...
    this.myId = `this-files-${++UploadButtonComponent.nextIdNumber}`;
  }
  // ...
}

<!--HTML-->
<label
  [for]="myId"
  class="btn btn-primary"
>
  Upload
</label>

<input (change)="onChange($event)" [id]="myId" type="file" accept="{{ accept }}" capture>
```